# Wordpress get page title as first function in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need to get the current page title. I am trying to use `echo 'In functions.php:'; wp_title();` in a functions.php script and it is returning blank. Also tried using the following script to initiate due to the deprecation notice:

```
function some_name(){
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'some_name' );
```

**It is still returning blank, although it's working inside my page templates. I need to get the page title to pass it into a cUrl POST.
Why is this happening and what am I missing here?**

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

Comment: Using this in functions.php on the first line:  echo 'Page name outside:'; get_the_title(); >> result is blank. I presume this likely happens because some Wordpress functions need to be initiate first? How to overcome this?

Comment: When exactly are you firing that curl call? The code shared above doesn't show any of that.

Comment: It seems that the cUrl is irrelevant as the current situation is rather getting wp_title() which doesn't seem to be working in functions.php in the first place although it should. If I could retrieve this I could pass the wp_title variable to the cUrl

Comment: It is relevant though: for you to get access to the current post/page title you need to use the right `action_*` hook, hence the question.

Comment: After posting a form I am using " public function __construct() {" and then inside this " $this->handlePostRequests();" and then " private function handlePostRequests($args = array()) {" which includes my cUrl